# How do platforms like OpenSea sync ERC721 token info in an efficient manner?

Tags: nft, erc-721, opensea

I assume OpenSea syncs all ERC721 token info to a private database. Current NFT ownership APIs don't provide the kind of filtering mechanisms that are available on OpenSea.

I'm wondering how exactly this kind of syncing might be done. Would it be viable to scan token transactions block by block and update the database every time a block is synced? Is there a more efficient way to achieve the same effect?